EEPROM, ee1004 and at24 drivers for temperature reading from SPDs
I am trying to read the temperatures of two DDR4 SDRAMS on my motherboard via Ubuntu 22. I can access memory temperatures on Windows.
When I checked with i2cdetect, I saw that my memories were not detected at all.
When i run decode-dimms with "eeprom" driver says the detected dimm does not exist:
“Number of SDRAM DIMMs detected and decoded: 0“
While trying it with "ee1004" and "at24", it returns a hardware not supported error:
“No eeprom found, the kernel probably does not support your hardware.”
While the HWInfo program in Windows can read memory temperatures, why can't Linux even detect them?
user@pc:/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/subsystem/hwmon1$ sudo i2cdetect -y  0
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:                         -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --                         
user@pc:/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/subsystem/hwmon1$ sudo i2cdetect -y  1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:                         08 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 1d -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: 40 -- -- -- 44 -- -- -- 48 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: 50 51 -- -- -- -- 56 57 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 6b -- -- -- --

Then, run commmand for each of 50, 51, 56, 57 adresses:
sudo modprobe jc42
root@pc:/home/user# sudo echo jc42 0x50 > /sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-1/new_device

Then,
 root@pc:/home/user# sudo i2cdetect -y 1
         0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
    00:                         08 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
    10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 1d -- -- 
    20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
    30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
    40: 40 -- -- -- 44 -- -- -- 48 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
    50: UU UU -- -- -- -- UU UU -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
    60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 6b -- -- -- -- 
    70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  

Output of sensors command for all of them are similar to this:
jc42-i2c-1-51
Adapter: SMBus I801 adapter at 8000
temp1:         -0.1°C  (low  =  -0.1°C)                  ALARM (LOW, HIGH, CRIT)
                       (high =  -0.1°C, hyst =  -6.1°C)
                       (crit =  -0.1°C, hyst =  -6.1°C)

Then,
sudo decode-dimms
# decode-dimms version 4.3

Memory Serial Presence Detect Decoder
By Philip Edelbrock, Christian Zuckschwerdt, Burkart Lingner,
Jean Delvare, Trent Piepho and others


Number of SDRAM DIMMs detected and decoded: 0


the memories would not be connected by I2C

@jsotola that's true, but the "SPD" memory on commercial memory modules usually are. There's no guarantee that bus is extended up into the kernel, though; there might be some non-I2C hardware abstraction on the mainboard. But "reading temperature": Not sure this is actually functionality of the microcontroller attached to that I²C bus. Even if it is, module manufacturers have resorted to quite horrible hacks to get things like "RGB lights controlled through I²C" working, for which they only needed to give a MS Windows tray icon full DMA access to the physical memory space… Linux might not do.

@jsotola the steps I followed to read sensors can be seen here: link Although I am not sure about that, i2c-tools is used because smbus is a type of i2c variant.

@alpd4 that doesn't mean SMBus and other I²C buses end up in the same "logical" linux driver. Note the big "IF you have a driver…"

Typically temperatures are accessed via the sensors package.  Install that and run sensors-detect to determine  if that can detect your memory hardware.  If it can then the results will be in the sensors command output.

@StephenHarris sensors package shows all measurements except memory temperature, unfortunately.

A modern system is likely to have more than one I2C/SMbus. Are you sure you're probing the correct one? Check with i2cdetect -l. You won't find the SDRAMs on the GPU's I2C bus, for example. If you don't seem to find the correct bus, please identify your motherboard/chipset. And unless you've ensured that the drivers providing the I2C/SM bus access are loaded in a fixed order, the I2C bus numbers may vary from one boot to the next. Memory temp sensor autodetection was added to the ee1004 module in kernel version 6.8; older kernels will need to load the jc42 module manually.

@telcoM there are two SMbuses, you are right. I have already the followed steps you mentioned. I edited the my first message and added to terminal outputs. You can review it.

The devices in the 0x50 .. 0x57 range would be the SPD EEPROMs, which would need the eeprom or at24 module for LPDDR3 and older, and the ee1004 module for DDR4 and newer. According to the specifications, the temperature sensors would be separate devices in the 0x18 .. 0x1f range, respectively.
For kernels older than 5.10, or for systems with more than 4 DIMM slots, the DDR4 SPD's have to be instantiated manually: for you it would be
echo ee1004 0x50 > /sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-1/new_device
echo ee1004 0x51 > /sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-1/new_device
echo ee1004 0x56 > /sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-1/new_device
echo ee1004 0x57 > /sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-1/new_device

The ee1004 module can then read the SPD EEPROM and see if it indicates the DIMM has a temperature sensor: bit 7 of byte 14 is set if the sensor is present.
If the ee1004 module works, you should be able to use sudo decode-dimms to display the SPD information in a human-readable format.
If a sensor exists, it should appear as a separate I2C device number in the 0x18 .. 0x1f range on the same bus, respectively. Newer kernels will automatically instantiate the device and auto-load the jc42 module for it once the ee1004 module is loaded; for older kernels, you'd have to do it manually.
According to your i2cdetect 1 output, your system would seem to have only one DIMM with a potential temperature sensor, at device number 0x1d. So you might try:
echo jc42 0x1d > /sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-1/new_device

The auto-detection for ee1004 was added in kernel version 5.10 for up to 4 DIMM slots; if you have more slots, you may still have to instantiate them manually until you get to kernel version 6.8, which increases the limit to 8 slots.
The auto-detection of thermal sensor was added in 2024-01-04 to the then-latest kernel version; I haven't checked if/how far it was backported. The default kernel of Ubuntu 22 might be too old to have that feature.
The auto-detection for SPD is based on DMI information, so if your BIOS/UEFI firmware has bad DMI data on the memory slots, that might explain why your SPDs are apparently not detected at all. Run sudo dmidecode -t memory and check the results for sanity. If insane values are found, a BIOS update might help.

I will repeat the steps with the current Ubuntu version. However, only two ram slots are occupied on the motherboard. The other two addresses show the empty slots. The current rams are the same models. I don't know why the temperature sensor is visible in only one. Maybe it will give more successful results with the current Kernel. I will let you know the status after I make the updates.
